# Combine 2 apks together so they are installed together

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game with some additional features, so I am using a normal JAVA development way and Unity for 3D graphics and the whole engine. These 2 parts are connected and both needed for the game.

The problem I am facing at the moment is how to combine them together so that user don't need to download 2 parts separately? Would much more convenient that download/install would happen together.

I have all the source files in Unity, but the only type I can export them is apk.

So I assume if there is a way to do, it should be done merging apks?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can merge apk without creating one big apk by coding them again but you can make an apk and that apk will only download these 2 apk and then delete itself, or download these 2 apk into same folder

With than user will only download one apk and apks will contain in the same place.

If you still need it you can try that and let me know if my advice is helpfull :)